# Sort Alphabet letters array in ascending order

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an PHP Indexed array having only alphabet letters randomly i want to sort this array in ascending order and also want to avoid duplication. e.g.

```
$letters = array("b","d","g","h","v","a","c","a");
```

I want like this

```
$letters = array("a","b","c","d","g","h","v");
```

How I can perform this scenario specially ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `sort()` to sort it, and `array_unique()` to remove the duplicate values.

```
sort($letters);
$letters = array_unique($letters);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sort function. Sort function accept parameter as array and sort it ascending order. Try the below code

```
$letters = array("b","d","g","h","v","a","c","a");
$letters = array_unique($letters);
sort($letters);
print_r($letters);
```